# Camera Perspective in Layout mode broken - Blender 2.81

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera

I am following the trusty old donut tutorial by Blender Guru, and I have run into an issue.

I am up to part 6, first render. The camera perspective in layout mode does not represent the render output. When I view the camera perspective in any other modes, e.g. Sculpting, the render does in fact represent the camera perspective.

What have I tried?
1. Restarting Blender
2. Load Factory Settings
3. Deleted the camera and created a new one

When I alter the camera angle, the camera angle changes in the layout mode (and all other modes), but the camera perspective in the layout mode is still different to the render output.

What is going on within layout? I am so confused.

[image: Layout Mode]

[image: Sculpting Mode]

[image: Final Render]

Comment: Try `0` on the numpad to switch into the camera view (in layout and all other workspaces) *or View > Cameras > Active Camera* in header menu of the 3d viewport.

Comment: @brockmann That's just basic navigation isn't it? I've tried that. I've also tried selecting the camera and pressing CTRL+0 to assign it as the active camera.

Comment: That looks more like you've zoomed in /panned into the camera view. Have you tried scrolling or Shift+MMB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear zoomed-in. Even though you have selected the camera view, it will retain the last zoom selected. Each workspace will retain it's own zoom levels. Just zoom out and hopefully that will resolve it. Oh and turn off `Lock Camera To View` as this sometimes confuses things. Once re-orientated, you can turn it back on.

Comment: Good idea @Derrick

Comment: Thanks. Zoom was the issue. I expected zoom in and out (scrolling) would affect the camera position. However, when you think about it, the focal length is 50mm (it is a fixed focal length, not varying; e.g. 50-100mm). So zooming just zooms the view port, not the camera focal length. I should have pressed "G" to reposition the camera.